# Using AddressSanitizer for NDK library

Tags: android, android-ndk, address-sanitizer

I have an Android app that has a Java part and an NDK library part. I want to test the NDK part, so I compiled it with AddressSanitizer following instructions here:
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerOnAndroid

Now, I want to run the app on my phone. According to the instruction above, I also need to run the **asan_device_setup** script provided by the ndk library. But when I ran the script I got

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I tried to directly run the app, but I ended up getting the following error, so I think the device setup step is required...

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so" not found
```

Any bit of help on solving this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The ASAN docs say it requires a rooted device. I'm not actually sure why that's required for arbitrary executables like tests (it's required for running your app with ASAN because it requires modifying `app_process` to laod the ASAN libraries). You could try pushing the ASAN libraries (look for `libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so` in `$NDK/toolchains/llvm`) to /data/local/tmp and then using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp /path/to/my/test` when running. If that works, we just need to update some tools and docs.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to find a rooted phone and run the app. I will also see if I can generate a native executable for test, and load the library in the way suggested by you.

Comment: I am trying to use AddressSanitizer to sanity check my own NDK code in an app.  I have rooted the device already -- since it seems most native memory troubleshooting tool requires that on Android (which is really obnoxious!).  But I get the issue noted above all the same.  I get different issues if I try --use-su (around a device being busy).  Overall, I can't get asan_device_setup to work.  This is invoking from OSX.  Windows is even more hopeless (at least prior to Windows 10) -- as only a shell script is provided and it fails under Cygwin.

Comment: So...  I edited asan_device_setup to rework the mount command as per https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/dGPQytapwe3 then ran it with the --set-su option.  That appeared to work based on the script output *but* apps built against ASAN still don't work and I don't see ASAN libraries installed in /system/lib in the end.